# HQL: Unknown column in where clause

Tags: mysql, select, count, hql

I am trying to count the rows of an hql query. I get the warning that the column TypeOfPermission does not exist. That strikes me as odd as a previous query does work. The line below gives me back 2 rows (as expected)

```
from ClientIdentity c left join fetch c.Permissions p where p.TypeOfPermission = :permissionType;
```

However using the following count query, the query fails as the column TypeOfPermission is now no longer recognised.

```
countQuery = "select count(*) from ClientIdentity c left join fetch c.Permissions p where p.TypeOfPermission = :permissionType";
long count = countQuery.UniqueResult<long>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using "Count(*)", "fetch" is not needed.

```
countQuery = "select count(*) from ClientIdentity c left join c.Permissions p where p.TypeOfPermission = :permissionType";
long count = countQuery.UniqueResult<long>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You change:

```
  c.Permissions to Permissions
```

Comment: Unfortunately this leads to a "Path expected for join!" as the Permission entity is no longer recognised.

Comment: The 'fetch' keyword is necessary when getting the actual rows. Removing the 'fetch' from my original count query seems to do the trick. No idea why that works though.